# carousel under the navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, navbar

i have a website bootstrap with a navbar scroll. i want a carousel full width under the navbar in the "intro-section" like this (http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel)[1](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel)

this is the code:

```
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">Servizi Offerti</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Cucine</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<!-- Intro Section -->
<section id="intro" class="intro-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Visit [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp)

**You should include the javascript dependencies**
Otherwise you won't achieve the behavior desired

> Plugins can be included individually (using Bootstrap's individual "carousel.js" file), or all at once (using "bootstrap.js" or "bootstrap.min.js").

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```